# What library for arbitrary precision library should I use?

Tags: math, arbitrary-precision

I need to program something that calculates a number to arbitrary precision...

but I need it to output the digits that are already "certain" (ie below some error bound) to a file so that there are digits to work on while the program keeps running.

Also, most libraries for arbitrary precision seem to require a fixed precision, but what if I wanted dynamic precision, ie, it would go on and on...

Comment: What languages might you be working with?  For arbitrary precision integers, rationals, and floating point in C, there is [GMP](http://gmplib.org/ "The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library") and [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/ "The GNU MPFR Library") but as far as I know these don't address an ability to represent fully the set of computable numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Most algorithms that calculate a number to extended precision require that all intermediate calculations are done to a somewhat higher precision to guarantee accurate results. You normally specify your final desired precision and that's the result that you get. If you want to output the "known" accurate digits during the calculation, you'll generally need to implement the algorithm and track the accurate digits yourself.

Without knowing what number you want to calculate, I can't offer any better suggestions.

GMP/MPIR only support very basic floating point calculations. MPFR, which requires either GMP or MPIR, provides a much broader set of floating point operations.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/). It's a fork of GMP but with (in my opinion) a more helpful and developer-friendly crew.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the second paragraph.  I think @llru is looking for something that will, for example, allow printing the first so many digits of π while yet more are still being computed.  AFAIK, GMP/MPFR/MPIR just give you arbitrary precision arithmetic with the sets of integers and rationals.

Comment: The precision can be changed whenever you want with `mpf_set_default_prec` so you're not tied to a specific compile-time precision. It won't automatically up the precision with operations but doing that would be a bad thing anyway - you should ask a mathematician about this one day if you want to see a rant :-)

Comment: Do you know if I'll be able to "see" the beginning part of the expansion while the computation is still running?